# how to use awk to pull fields and make them variables to do data calculation

Tags: math, awk

I am using `awk` to compute Mean Frational Bias form a data file. How can I make the data points a variable to call in to my equation?

Input.....

```
       col1   col2
row #1 Yavg:  14.87954
row #2 Xavg:  20.83804
row #3 Ystd:  7.886613
row #4 Xstd:  8.628519
```

I am looking to feed into this equation....

```
MFB = .5 * (Yavg-Xavg)/[(Yavg+Xavg)/2]
```

output....

```
       col1   col2
row #1 Yavg:  14.87954
row #2 Xavg:  20.83804
row #3 Ystd:  7.886613
row #4 Xstd:  8.628519
row #5 MFB: (computed value)
```

currently trying to use the following code to do this but not working....

```
var= 'linear_reg-County119-O3-2004-Winter2013-2018XYstats.out.out'
val1=$(awk -F, OFS=":" "NR==2{print $2; exit}" <$var)
val2=$(awk -F, OFS=":" "NR==1{print $2; exit}" <$var)
#MFB = .5*((val2-val1)/((val2+val1)/2))
awk '{ print "MFB :" .5*((val2-val1)/((val2+val1)/2))}'  >>     linear_regCounty119-O3-2004-Winter2013-2018XYstats-wMFB.out
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2):

Try running: `awk -f mfb.awk input.txt` where

`mfb.awk`:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ": " } # set the separators
{ v[$1] = $2; print } # store each line in an array named "v"
END {
  MFB = 0.5 * (v["Yavg"] - v["Xavg"]) / ((v["Yavg"] + v["Xavg"]) / 2)
  print "MFB", MFB
  }
```

`input.txt`:

```
Yavg: 14.87954
Xavg: 20.83804
Ystd: 7.886613
Xstd: 8.628519
```

Output:

```
Yavg: 14.87954
Xavg: 20.83804
Ystd: 7.886613
Xstd: 8.628519
MFB: -0.166823
```

Alternatively, `mfb.awk` can be the following, resembling your original code:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ": " }
{ print }
NR == 1 { Yavg = $2 } NR == 2 { Xavg = $2 }
END {
  MFB = 0.5 * (Yavg - Xavg) / ((Yavg + Xavg) / 2)
  print "MFB", MFB
  }
```

Note that you don't usually toss variables back and forth between the shell and Awk (at least when you deal with a single input file).